Animated Objects vs Existing Objects
How spells Animate Objects, Possess Object and similar ones interact with pre-existing features of objects?

Let's say I animate Medium Object out of something that is entirely/mostly made out of adamantium? Medium object has 2 CP while adamantium upgrade costs 6 CP.

Or let's go further and assume I animate statue that already has weapons, is made of adamantium and technically has 20+ CP worth of upgrades already, before I animate it.

Another example would be giving animated object an actual weapon, crafted specifically for such use. Most likely oversized one. Can it use the weapon without buying weapon upgrade for CP?


What happens in those cases? Do I still get CP to spend while pre-existing features are free? Do I loose available CP because pre-existing features are already worth more CP than I have available?

The spell "animate objects" makes no reference to the actual condition of the objects being animated. This could, for example, result in a cloth rug being given the "adamantium" quality. From what I see, there's a lot of DM-specific ruling on the relationship between original objects and their animated versions. Furthermore, a previous answer (link below) states that the animated objects are treated as summoned creatures, this implies that the force animating the object is completely different than the object itself.
As for putting weapons on the animated object, the second linked answer states that handing a construct a weapon doesn't mean it knows how to use it. Also consider that the animated object cannot be commanded to hold or use the weapon.
(See the first answer, unlike "summon monster", animated objects cannot be commanded to take actions other than "attack this target")
Also, casting the spell on a weapon or an object that incorporates a weapon won't necessarily give them extra attack properties, either. Consider the example of the stone golem

While it may be sculpted to carry a stone shield or stone weapon such as a sword, these aesthetic choices do not affect its combat abilities.

So, tldr; the original object has very little effect on the actual stats and abilities of the resulting animated object, unless the GM decides to make it so. And, to be fair, if I were GM, I'd be giving some house rules on this matter, because it seems cooler to reward players finding the right object for the right purpose.
Pfsrd page: animated objects
Creature-
https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object
Spell-
https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-objects/
Animated objects basics
How does the "Animate Objects" spell work?
Weapons and constructs
Construct with a crossbow

This completely ignores Possess Object case mentioned in question. I don't have to command anything in this case, I am the thing and I know what a sword is and how to use it. Would also be nice to have some rules quotations on the "rug can be given adamantium quality", because it sounds nonsensical, big time. I do give a point up for Golem Reference. This solves at least part of one scenario.
